# stats.nba.com <Response [403]>

Tags: python

The code below is returning Response [403] but I have other codes that scrape the same URL without issue. Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is here?

```
import requests
import csv
from random import choice
import pandas as pd

desktop_agents = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.1 Safari/602.2.14',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0']

url_template = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashptstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom={date}&DateTo={date}&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PerMode=Totals&PlayerExperience=&PlayerOrTeam=Player&PlayerPosition=&PtMeasureType=SpeedDistance&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight="

lineup_df = pd.DataFrame()

def random_headers():
    return {'User-Agent': choice(desktop_agents),'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}

df = pd.read_csv('NBADates.csv')
df.to_dict('series')

url_list=[url_template.format(date=date) for date in df.loc[ : ,"Date"]]

for url in url_list:

    data = requests.get(url, random_headers)
    print(data)
```

Comment: 403 means
The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any). You can check if other code is passing any cookie to authenticate or authentication token is in the env variable.

Comment: my guess is that you're being rate-limited.  Often sticking a second or two of `time.sleep()` between calls will prevent this kind of rejection.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up removing the random headers and put 1 header after the request, which solved the problem.